# Calling function with a dynamic argument type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to call a function with different types because i want sometimes to call it with the event object and sometimes with an array or anything else than an event

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    if( e is Event ) { // something like this
        // do some stuff with e.target.value
    } else { // different argument type
        ...
    }
}
```

Calling it with event object

```
<input type="text" onChange={ (e) => onChange(e) } />
```

Calling it with an different argument type

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={ (e) => {
    let newValues;
    // do some calculation
    ...
    onChange(newValues); 
}}/>
...
```

Comment: `if (Array.isArray(e)) { console.log('an array') } else { console.log("event object") }`

Comment: I'd just through out there that calling with two entirely different types isn't great. Why not make dedicated functions?

Comment: @ziggywiggy i can't do that in my case it must be just one function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you do `typeof e` in both cases you will get `object` as a response because event and array are both objects in javascript.

To detect if an object is an array you have `Array.isArray()`.

And to detect if an object is a DOM event you could do `e instanceof Event`.

In reactjs you have to change it to `e.nativeEvent instanceof Event`

So you could do something like this:

```js
const a = document.getElementById('test');

const onClick = (e) => {
    // use (e.nativeEvent instanceof Event) in reactjs instead
    if(e instanceof Event) { 
        // do some stuff with e.target.value
        console.log("Response: I received an event");
    } else if (Array.isArray(e)) { // it's an array
        console.log("Response: I received an array");
    }
}

a.addEventListener('click', onClick);

console.log('Call the method passing an array');
onClick([2,3,4]);
```

```html
<div id='test'>click</div>
```

Comment: is `e.target` a sure thing ? i edited my question i want just to check if it is an event

Comment: `e instanceof Event` it is not working, it is always evaluated to `false`

Comment: i think because my event come from an input `onChange` event and i am using Google Chrome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191801/discussion-between-f-cj-and-youssef).

Comment: @Youssef In reactjs you are using SyntheticEvents so you have to use `e.nativeEvent instanceof Event`

Comment: thanks @f-CJ it worked with `e.nativeEvent instanceof Event` so I can use it without any probelem ?

Comment: @Youssef Yes but consider using two different methods as other users stated in the comments. It is usually not a good practice to receive different types for the same function argument. Anyway, you are welcome! See you around.